# Preserving functor positivity when going via product vs. vector

Tags: recursion, types, agda

In the following code, the definition of `μ₁` is accepted by Agda as a strictly positive functor, which makes sense. If I tie the knot via a product, as in `μ₂`, it is still accepted. However, if I try to go via a vector, as in `μ₃`, it is not accepted anymore.

```
data F : Set where
  X : F

⟦_⟧₁ : F → Set → Set
⟦ X ⟧₁ A = A

data μ₁ (f : F) : Set where
  Fix₁ : ⟦ f ⟧₁ (μ₁ f) → μ₁ f

open import Data.Product

⟦_⟧₂ : F → (Set × Set) → Set
⟦ X₁ ⟧₂ (A , _) = A

open import Data.Unit

data μ₂ (f : F) : Set where
  Fix₂ : ⟦ f ⟧₂ (μ₂ f , ⊤) → μ₂ f

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Vec

⟦_⟧₃ : ∀ {n} → F → Vec Set (suc n) → Set
⟦ X ⟧₃ (A ∷ _) = A

data μ₃ (f : F) : Set where
  Fix₃ : ⟦ f ⟧₃ [ μ₃ f ] → μ₃ f
```

The error message for `μ₃` is

```
μ₃ is not strictly positive, because it occurs
in the third argument to ⟦_⟧₃
in the type of the constructor Fix₃
in the definition of μ₃.
```

What is the fundamental difference between `μ₂` and `μ₃`? Is there a way to get something like `μ₃` working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm mostly guessing. `_×_` is a `record` and `Vec` is a `data`. Agda rejects `μ₂`, when `_×_` is defined as a `data`:

```
data Pair (A B : Set₁) : Set₁
  where pair : A -> B -> Pair A B

⟦_⟧₃ : F → Pair Set Set → Set
⟦ X ⟧₃ (pair A _) = A

data μ₃ (f : F) : Set where     
  Fix₃ : ⟦ f ⟧₃ (pair (μ₃ f) ⊤) → μ₃ f
```

Results in "`μ₃` is not strictly positive, because it occurs...". But if you define `⟦_⟧₃` as

```
⟦_⟧₃ : F → Pair Set Set → Set
⟦ X ⟧₃ _ = ⊤
```

or

```
⟦_⟧₃ : F → Pair Set Set → Set
⟦ _ ⟧₃ (pair A _) = A
```

then everything is OK (your `μ₂` is a bit misleading, since there is no pattern matching on `F` too). In the second case Agda just normalizes the expression, since there is no pattern matching on the first argument and the second is in the WHNF, so `⟦_⟧₃` is totally eliminated. But I don't know, how Agda resolves the first case. Something ad hoc, I suppose.

Your `μ₂` typechecks, because [Agda eliminates pattern matching on records](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Records):

> ```
> map : {A B : Set} {P : A → Set} {Q : B → Set}
>       (f : A → B) → (∀ {x} → P x → Q (f x)) →
>       Σ A P → Σ B Q
> map f g (x , y) = (f x , g y)
> ```
>
> The clause above is internally translated into the following one:
>
> ```
> map f g p = (f (Σ.proj₁ p) , g (Σ.proj₂ p))
> ```

So it's just like the

```
⟦_⟧₃ : F → Pair Set Set → Set
⟦ X ⟧₃ _ = ⊤
```

case.

Also, `⟦_⟧₃` will typecheck, if you remove pattern matching on the first argument.

**UPDATE**

No, it's not about pattern matching elimination, since this definition

```
data Pair (A B : Set₁) : Set₁
  where pair : A -> B -> Pair A B

fst : ∀ {A B} -> Pair A B -> A
fst (pair x y) = x

⟦_⟧₃ : F → Pair Set Set → Set
⟦ X ⟧₃ p = fst p

data μ₃ (f : F) : Set where     
  Fix₃ : ⟦ f ⟧₃ (pair (μ₃ f) ⊤) → μ₃ f
```

is rejected too.

Comment: For my real (non-minimal) use case, `⟦_⟧₃` very much needs to pattern match on its argument (since `F` has more than one constructor)

Comment: @Cactus, I don't think you should accept my answer. It's not even an answer.